An error has occurred which PowerShell cannot handle. A remote session might have ended
I am evaluating Web Front End solution for backend PowerShell scripts - every single time service request fails here:
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName dcName -ConfigurationName 
           DomainAdmins

Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {...}
                                
Error: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Session'. The argument is 
null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try 
the command again. [dcName] An error has occurred which PowerShell cannot 
handle. A remote session might have ended.

Other, free Web Front End solution has no issues whatsoever. Vendor is saying something is misconfigured in my environment which obviously is not the case here since free solution works flawlessly with PS remoting inside the PS script.
Does anyone have any clue what I can do here not requiring paid support by Vendor (we are still in PoC phase) - PS remoting is the backbone of all service requests so having it working flawlessly is a must.

$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName dcName -ConfigurationName 
           DomainAdmins

Check if there is any NW issue.
Test-Connestion -ComputerName dcName

using Credential
$credential = Get-Credential
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName dcName -ConfigurationName 
           DomainAdmins -Credential $credential
   

Firewall/WinRM Configuration.
Enable-PSRemoting -FOrce


Everything is ok regarding networking/WinRM configuration - this has to be something inside Web Front End itself, otherwise other solution would not have worked. Both are running on top of IIS.
Also, in PowerShell itself all commands are working fine but when script is "executed" by Web Front End I get error above.

This might help but do not know if I can do anything on my end:
"Message": "BinaryFormatter serialization and deserialization are disabled within this application. See https://aka.ms/binaryformatter for more information.",
